# Is there a .NET construct like Java's enum.ordinal()?

Tags: .net, enums, f#

If I have the following enum in F#:

```
type Note =
    | C = 0
    | D = 2
    | E = 4
    | F = 5
    | G = 7
    | A = 9
    | B = 11
```

But at some points, I need the ordinals of the items inside of it, such that `Note.C = 1, Note.D = 2,` etc. Obviously in other languages, `foo.ordinal()` would work, but in here is it necessary to use a function like such:

```
let getNoteOrdinal = function
    |Note.C -> 1
    |Note.D -> 2
    |Note.E -> 3
    |Note.F -> 4
    //etc
```

Is that function necessary or is there something better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enums in .NET are just a layer on top of an integral type, in this case your values are `int`.

Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/enumerations), you can do a simple conversion to get that value, for example:

```ml
let value = int Note.B
```

Where `value` in this case would be `11`.

To find the ordinal, as you can make use of a built-in function that gives you an array of all the values in order and then find the index of the one you're after. For example:

```ml
let getNoteOrdinal (note: Note) =
    let values = Enum.GetValues(typeof<Note>)
    Array.IndexOf(values, note) + 1

let value = getNoteOrdinal Note.E
```

Where `value` in this case would be `3`.

You can take this one step further as @ReedCopsey suggests and make a generic function that will give you the ordinal for *any* enum value:

```ml
let getEnumOrdinal (e: 'a when 'a : enum<'b> and 'a : equality) =    
    let values = Enum.GetValues(e.GetType())
    Array.IndexOf(values, e) + 1
```

Comment: Note that this is a different number than the one the OP is after, but in general, I find this to be a better approach in most cases anyways.

Comment: @ReedCopsey ah, so it is! Teach me to read properly. I’ll leave here as it may be useful.

Comment: Yeah, I'm asking if there's a built-in way to get the `ordinal` a la Java etc. and not the `value`.

Comment: btw - if you want to steal the constraint from my answer, I'll delete mine. That would make this type safe (though mine works for any enum, not just Note)

Comment: @ReedCopsey can add, sure. Mine was specific for `Note`, so I'll add yours in as a generic version for any enum.

Comment: I'll accept this answer but with all that being said, I take it that there really isn't something in the .NET ecosystem that will do the same thing as `enum.ordinal()` right out of the box?

Comment: @LSM07 I’m pretty certain. One tip with F# when questions like this arise is to search for similar solutions in C#. Having just done that, the only results I can find are similar to this implementation.

Comment: @LSM07 In general, .NET suggests you consider the ordinal an implementation detail, not something to base logic upon. It's pretty much frowned upon to use it. What is the use case for this?

Comment: Personal project, music notation/theory software

Answer (score 1):

I suggest not using an enum at all in F# unless it is required for interoperation with another .NET language. You can use a discriminated union and store the note values in an array (this is a module level value that is evaluated once when the application starts). Then you can write functions that use the array.

```
type Note = C | D | E | F | G | A | B

let noteValues =
    [| C, 0
       D, 2
       E, 4
       F, 5
       G, 7
       A, 9
       B, 11 |]

let getNoteValue note =
    noteValues |> Array.find (fun (n, _) -> note = n) |> snd

let getNoteOrdinal note =
    noteValues |> Array.findIndex (fun (n, _) -> n = note) |> (+) 1
```

Example usage:

```
getNoteValue C // 0
getNoteValue D // 2

getNoteOrdinal C // 1
getNoteOrdinal D // 2
```